# Angularjs $stateChangeStart callback, all parameters except 'toState' are null

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have this code

```
 unsavedChangesManager.clearLocationHandler = $scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
            unsavedChangesManager.checkUnsavedChanges(function () {
                unsavedChangesManager.clearLocationHandler();
                $state.go(toState.name); // here I want to also append the toParams. However this param doesnt have a value. 
            });
            event.preventDefault();
        });
```

Here I am trying to intercept the `$stateChangeStart` event to check if there is unsaved changes on current page, if so, notify user and according to user preference either stay on the page or change the state.  The issue here is when the event is fired, the `toState` parameter has a value, the `event` param is `undefined`, and the other parameters are not set to anything. I am wondering why.

I am using angularjs 1.2.28 and ui-router 0.2.15.

Comment: did you tried `$state.go(toState.name, {param: paramValue, param1: paramValue1,...soOn})`?

Comment: Thanks for you response Pankaj but my question was not about the how to call $state.go.  My question is  except 'toState' all other paramters that I passed to callback , 'toParams','fromState' and 'fromParams' are not being assigned any value. i.e. they are null. Why?

Comment: I was able to solved this partially (at least I am unblocked for the moment).  I have learnt that $stateChangeStart is fired at root level, so what I did was to change  $scope.$on  to $rootScope.$on.  Now I am able to get 'toState' and 'toParams'  which at the moment the values I was looking for. Note: event though it works (partially) I still dont know why , $scope.$on wasn't able to work after all because the event propagates to child scope.